# Typescript, useContext(), error: Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-context

I'm trying to use useContext() hook in typescript, but I expireance numerouse errores.
useState initialy is equal to empty array of interface `Phone` which is imported, and then state and setState are passed in `value` prop .

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Phone } from '../types/Phone';

type SetValue = (value: Phone[]) => void;

interface LikedContextInterface {
  likedGadgets: Phone[];
  setLikedGadgets: SetValue;
}

export const likedContext = createContext<LikedContextInterface>([]);

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const LikedContextProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const [likedGadgets, setLikedGadgets] = useState<Phone[]>([]);

  return (
    <likedContext.Provider value={{ likedGadgets, setLikedGadgets }}>
      { children }
    </likedContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

in terminal I recieve following errors:
`Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LikedContextInterface'.`
`Type 'never[]' is missing the following properties from type 'LikedContextInterface': likedGadgets, setLikedGadgets`

Edited!!!

So here is working code:

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Phone } from '../types/Phone';

type SetValue = (value: Phone[]) => void;

type LikedContextInterface = {
  likedGadgets: Phone[];
  setLikedGadgets: SetValue;
};

export const likedContext = createContext<LikedContextInterface>({
  likedGadgets: [],
  setLikedGadgets: () => {},
});

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const LikedContextProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const [likedGadgets, setLikedGadgets] = useState<Phone[]>([]);

  return (
    <likedContext.Provider value={{ likedGadgets, setLikedGadgets }}>
      { children }
    </likedContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize context correctly by providing initial value which is LikedContextInterface:

```
export const likedContext = createContext<LikedContextInterface>({
   likedGadgets: [],
   setLikedGadgets: (value: Phone[]) => {},
});
```

Comment: Thanks. So I provided empty array as an initial value of useState hook. But I should have provided properties that I pass inside value prop during initialization of createContext function as arguments.
PS. in common react js I never passed any arguments in createContext function, so thats where confusion came from)